# Prevent Setup Project from automatically Digitally Signing my output MSI

Tags: visual-studio-2015, digital-signature, setup-project

I'm running visual studio 2015 with [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) for creating setup projects.

Once I build my setup project, the MSI file output I see is already digitally signed by a local certificate claiming to be Microsoft which is preventing me from signing it with my own code signing certificate.

Is there a way to prevent the installer project from automatically signing the MSI file ?

Comment: Resolved this by adding a post build event to the Installer project which digitally signs the msi which replaces the other digital signature.